# Shaping or structuring the data in R for Market Basket Analysis

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis

I have a dataset with columns like Order ID, Productname and others

```
Order ID.   Productname
121.         Shirt
122.         Tie
121.         Socks
122.         Belt
122.         Shirt
```

I want the data to be shaped like below to perform the Market Basket Analysis in R

```
Order Id.   Productname
121          Shirt,Socks
122.         Tie,Belt,Shirt
```

I have come across different ways of doing it some using aggregate function or summarize function.But I am not able to get the output

Please share what functions or method to do this

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(Productname ~ ., df1, FUN = toString)
#  Order ID.      Productname
#1       121     Shirt, Socks
#2       122 Tie, Belt, Shirt
```